# You don't have sufficient permissions to open the element or perform the desired action

Tags: symfony, pimcore

I am working in pimcore and after I have created areabrick I get this error message in my admin panel:

```
You don't have sufficient permissions to open the element or perform the desired action.
```

Here is the part of the code:

```
<!-- Slider -->
<section id="slider">
  <?= $this->areablock('landingAreaBlock'); ?>
</section>
```

I have taken it from the documentation and also I have to mention that I am logged in as the admin user.